# How to test code when dealing with MongooseArray in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, supertest

I am trying to do some integration tests using Supertest. My object schema contains an array:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  tags: {
      type: Array,
      lowercase: true
   }
});
```

I am using Mongoose and when running my tests I am always encounter this issue with getting an MongooseArray instead of Array and I am not sure how to deal with this.

```
 - Expected value
    + Received value

    - CoreMongooseArray [
    + Array [
        "tag1",
      ]
```

What can I do to always get an Array ?
Where do I have to make my changes ? In my code or test ?

Here is an example(test) when I use `lean` that works:

```
    await exec();

    const updatedCategory = await Category.findById(category._id).lean();

    expect(updatedCategory.name).toBe(name);
    expect(updatedCategory.tags).toEqual(tags);
```

And here is one that doesn't work:

```
    const res = await exec();

    expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('_id', category._id.toHexString());
    expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('name', category.name);
    expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('tags', category.tags);
```

In this case I am checking if the property exists and doesn't work.

edit:

Here is the exec() function for the test that works (PUT route):

```
const exec = async () => {
    return await request(app)
      .put('/api/categories/' + id)
      .set('x-auth-token', token)
      .send({ name: name, tags: tags });
  }
```

Here is the exec() function for the test that fails (DELETE route):

```
const exec = async () => {
    return await request(app)
      .delete('/api/categories/' + id)
      .set('x-auth-token', token)
      .send();
  }
```

edit3:

Here is the result when displaying `res.body` on the console:

```
{
      "_id": "5db58e63fa9c143794484eea",
      "tags": [
        "tag1"
      ],
      "name": "category1",
      "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: have you tried calling `.lean()` on your query?

Comment: I use that for a query in my test and it somehow works, but I have another case when I am suing toHaveProperty from superset, this one doesn't work. So it doesn't work when I am checking for a property

Comment: I updated my question with some examples of using lean()

Comment: what does your `exec` function look line in the one that doesn't work?

Comment: I updated my answer with both exec() functions

Comment: are you sure that the handler for `app.delete` returns the deleted object? what mongoose method are you using for deleting the entity? some won't return the deleted object.

Comment: This is how I delete it: const category = await Category.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

Comment: I get the object, but the test for tags is incorrect because of the type MongooseArray

Comment: you can call `.lean()` on `findByIdAndDelete` too ?

Comment: yes, but I get the same failure inside my test

Comment: Is `res.body` decoded? or still JSON?

Comment: I get this if I printed to console.log: [object Object]

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.body, undefined, 2));` what do you get?

Comment: Updated my question again with the response.

Comment: Intresting... Sounds stupid, but try. `const newRes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.body))` and test `newRes`

Comment: Same result, still getting a MongooseArray ...

Comment: meh :/ im exhausted for ideas, ill share hope it works for you!